# eas build - Duplicate resources

Tags: android, react-native, expo, build.gradle, release

I'm trying to run eas build for android but it's failing every time with the same error **Duplicate resources [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_logo] ..."**. I read other posts and deleted all drawable files from app/src/main/res. this is how res folder looks like now but I still get the same error.

[image]

I searched for my project to check if I have another drawable file somewhere but nothing came up.  Please help, any advise is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: As you can see, there are images in the res folder. You can erase all the files in the res folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that some images had the same name, so after I renamed them, everything worked fine without deleting all these folders.

Comment: you saved my day. I have been struggling for 3 days

Comment: Same here, thanks & lol to the fact that can not be...

Answer (score 1):

### Rename image files to have different filenames, even if they already have different extensions.

Evidently, random.jpg ~= random.png ~= random.gif

I had random.jpg, random.gif, and random.png and received this error. After changing to randomJpg.jpg, randomGif.gif, and randomPng.png the error went away.